# Using Gulp, is it possible to add environment variables as a comment into CSS? (for example the package.json version)

Tags: gulp

Is it possible to pipe through specific environment variables in an SCSS file using a gulp setup?

Could you, for example, use something like:

```
/*! %version% */
```

Where version would be the version number as used in package.json.

Answer (score 1):

From [gulp-header](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-header) example:

```
// using data from package.json

var pkg = require('./package.json');

//var banner = ['/**',
//  ' * <%= pkg.name %> - <%= pkg.description %>',
//  ' * @version v<%= pkg.version %>',
//  ' * @link <%= pkg.homepage %>',
//  ' * @license <%= pkg.license %>',
//  ' */',
//  ''].join('\n');

// in your case all you need is:
var banner = ['/*! <%= pkg.version %> */\n'];

// in your task 
gulp.src('./foo/*.scss')
  .pipe(header(banner, { pkg : pkg } ))
  .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
  // if you are using sourcemaps, init them after injecting the header commment

  .pipe(sass().on("error", sass.logError))
  .pipe(sourcemaps.write("sourcemaps"))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'))
```